# Copy column to another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have got two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `dbtest1` (
    `VIDEO_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `CHANNEL_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `PRICE` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`VIDEO_ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE `dbtest2` (
        `VIDEO_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `WEIGHT` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`VIDEO_ID`)
    )
    COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    ;
```

I want to copy the column `CHANNEL_ID` to dbtest2.

The tables are only to demonstrate, what i want to do.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create the channel_id column in the dbtest2 and then copy data from the first table into it?

Comment: Yes that is my plan, for each entry in dbtest1 exists at least one entry in dbtest2

Comment: What about the other two columns? where will the values for VIDEO_ID and WEIGHT come from? say you'll VIDEO_ID from first table, but WEIGHT?

Comment: For each entry in 'dbtest1' exists at least one entry in 'dbtest2' with the same value for 'VIDEO_ID', and additional value for 'weight'. There is some redundancy, I know, but i need this because of performance issues (the actual tables have another structur, but the example shows the problem)

Comment: do you actually need that data duplicated in both tables? If you just want to see it in a column as if it was part of the table you can easily create a VIEW, which you then query exactly the same as a table.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to copy the column type and data the solution is this:

```
ALTER TABLE 'dbtest2' ADD COLUMN 'column1' INT NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO 'dbtest2' ('column1')
  SELECT 'dbtest1'.'column1'
  FROM 'dbtest1';
```

Comment: How do I ensure, that the order of the rows is exactly like in dbtest1? I was thinking about a join on `VIDEO_ID`

Comment: GIve a select an order by 'dbtest1'.Id